# Generic type inference from an specific function argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How to make TS infer a type from a specific function argument between multiple arguments?

```
type TypeA<T extends string> = Record<T, unknown>;
type TypeB<T> = { array: T[] };

function fn<T extends string>(a: TypeA<T>, b: TypeB<T>): void {}

fn(
    {
        attr1: 1,
        attr2: 2,
    },
    {
        array: ["attr1"],
    }
);
```

In this example, TS complains about the attribute `attr2` from the first argument.

```
Argument of type '{ attr1: number; attr2: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TypeA<"attr1">'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'attr2' does not exist in type 'TypeA<"attr1">'. Did you mean to write 'attr1'?ts(2345)
```

It means that `T` is inferred from the array but what I want to accomplish is T to be inferred from the first argument, which is the object's keys. `T` should be `"attr1" | "attr2"` instead.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are trying to achieve:

```html
function fn<T, K extends keyof T>(a:T, b: { array: K[] }): void {}

fn(
    {
        attr1: 1,
        attr2: 2,
    },
    {
        array: ["attr1"], // ok
    }
);

fn(
    {
        attr1: 1,
        attr2: 2,
    },
    {
        array: ["attr1", "attr3"], // Type '"attr3"' is not assignable to type '"attr1" | "attr2"'.
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need to infer `a` argument:

```js
type TypeA<T extends string> = Record<T, unknown>;
type TypeB<T> = { array: T[] };

function fn<T extends string, Rec extends TypeA<T>>(a: Rec, b: TypeB<T>): void { }

fn(
  {
    attr1: 1,
    attr2: 2,
  },
  {
    array: ["attr1", 'attr2'], // ok
  }
);

fn(
  {
    attr1: 1,
    attr2: 2,
  },
  {
    array: ["attr12"], // expected error
  }
);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEA8MoQB7AgOwCYGcp9gAnAS2wHMA%20KAXigCUIBjAexNxQBooBXbAGtsbAO7ZqAbgBQoSLHgAhFLQYBvKAEMSJTSABcsANoBdKAF8Z0gGYCWwMm2xRr2FGkw4CRUhUq9mFg8sPEI4SGQYamoACk1DQN4AI0NwiGUogEpDADc2MlwoDXNpG2wY6SgiyqqtYFIARkMG7hqqzXqSACZDLtaq837q2q0dPUMjACIOxsneAHIZ7vmTXgB6Nag2QRqSzKtXCqq1NrrG5qH2zp6oPt2hk5HtXQMoKaWGrsnVqA2PSHsEEKEB0HF20n2QA)

YOu can find more information about function argument infering in my [blog](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

**UPDATE**

> In the playground, TS is complaining about attr1 of the first argument
> of the second fn call, not the array value as you expected
> My bad,

```js
type TypeA<T extends string> = Record<T, unknown>;
type TypeB<T> = { array: T[] };

function fn<
  T extends string,
  Rec extends TypeA<T>,
  Arr extends Array<keyof Rec>
>(a: Rec, b: { array: [...Arr] }): void { }

fn(
  {
    attr1: 1,
    attr2: 2,
  },
  {
    array: ["attr1", 'attr2'], // ok
  }
);

fn(
  {
    attr1: 1,
    attr2: 2,
  },
  {
    array: ["attr12"], // expected error
  }
);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEA8MoQB7AgOwCYGcp9gAnAS2wHMA%20KAXigCUIBjAexNxQBooBXbAGtsbAO7ZqAbgBQoSLHgAhFLQYBvKAEMSJTSABcsANoBdKAF8Z0gGYCWwMm2xRr2JNKiw0mHASKkKSm4PJlZvLDxCOEhkGGpgzwQdcN9CJN0QJEEIEDZrUJZqaWoACk1DZhZeACNDDW0MwyMAOlb0s3MASkMANzYyXCgNc2kbbBKQtRDPTWBSAEZDeYTPLTmSACZDDZXzFanVrR09JoAiWYXT3gByC83rk14AeieoNkEQkc6rVwnPA9Wd0WUGW0zWpC2UB2n32YIaJygRnO63mG1OjygL28kHsEEGEB0HE%200m%20QA)

Comment: In the playground, TS is complaining about `attr1` of the first argument of the second `fn` call, not the array value as you expected.

Comment: @MateusPires good point, I made an update

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to the other answers:

```
type TypeA<T extends string> = Record<T, unknown>;
type TypeB<T> = { array: T[] };

function fn<
  T extends string,
  V extends TypeA<T>
>(
  a: V,
  b: TypeB<keyof V>
): void { }

fn(
  {
    attr1: 1,
    attr2: 2,
  },
  {
    array: ["attr1"],
  }
);

fn(
  {
    attr1: 1,
    attr2: 2,
  },
  {
    array: ["attr3"], // Type '"attr3"' is not assignable to type '"attr1" | "attr2"'.
  }
);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEA8MoQB7AgOwCYGcp9gAnAS2wHMA%20KAXigCUIBjAexNxQBooBXbAGtsbAO7ZqAbgBQoSLHgAhFLQYBvKAEMSJTSABcsANoBdKAF8Z0gGYCWwMm2xRr2JNKiw0mHASKkKSm4PKAA1byw8QjhIZBhqaWoAChDNQ1DgzwAjQxiIZUEIEDZrMISASkMANzYyXCgNc2kbbBTPNRDPTWBSAEZDXszPLR6SACZDMaHzIY7hrR09QyMAIm6%20lZNp6XKrVzaGzpG%20gaGu0YmoKZCZkLnh7V0DKFX1kgBmTd4Aem%20FeQA5GtRp8AVAyIQRMAtPh8GRKNhNFkADbQYBsKByaBAt69FZQAA%20UGBpDGKwBADobjtJEA)